# Delete products url not working in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want a user to delete a product when he clicks unlike button but I'm getting an error `404` url not found, but I have the url.

If I put `dd($product)` before `$like = Like::findOrFail($product);`
it displays the `id(4)` but if I put `dd($like)`, then it throws an error `404`. How can I make this function work?.

Controller

```
 public function destroy($product)
 {
   $like = Like::findOrFail($product);
     dd($like);
   $like->delete();

  return 'done';
 }
```

Blade

```
  <a class="remove"  href="{{ route('product.unlike', ['product' => $product->id]) }}" > Unlike </a>
```

Route

```
 Route::get('product/{product}/unlike', ['as' => 'product.unlike', 'uses' => 'LikeController@destroy']);
```

Like.php

```
  class Like extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;

protected $table = 'likeables';

protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'product_id',
    'likeable_id',
    'likeable_type',
];

public function products()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Product', 'likeable');
}
```

Comment: Seems there is no product with the given id in the DB.

Comment: There is a product(4) in database @PaulSpiegel

Comment: Look in the table which is configured in the `Like` model!

Comment: Yeah I see the id 4 @PaulSpiegel

Comment: If you `dd($product)` what are the results?

Comment: if I dd($product) It shows 4 @EyadJaabo

Comment: What do you get when you inspect the href attribute of the a tag?

Comment: how do I inspect ?@linktoahref

Comment: Could you try `Like::where('id', $product)->delete();`

Comment: Inspect it in the browser, the rendered a tag

Comment: I have tried `Like::where('id', $product)->delete();` and it redirect back but the product is not deleted @EyadJaabo

Comment: If I inspect the href in browser I see like the way it is in blade or maybe I didn't get the point @linktoahref

Comment: Could you update the question with `dd(Like::all())` results?

Answer (score 0):

delete request should be `post request not get`

`web.php`

```
Route::delete('product/{product}/unlike','LikeController@destroy')->name('product.unlike');
```

`blade.php`

```
<form action="{{ route('product.unlike',[$product->id]) }}" method="post">
 @csrf
 @method('DELETE')
 <button type="submit" class="remove"> Unlike </button>
</form>
```

`controller`

```
use App\Product;

...

public function destroy(Product $product) {
 $product->delete(); 
 return 'done'; 
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm getting this `The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST` @Ben96

Comment: Yeah I have tried it and I'm getting the `404` error again @Ben96

Comment: public function destroy($product)
 {
   $product->delete();
   return 'done';
 }

Comment: I get `Call to a member function delete() on string"` @Ben96

Comment: That deletes product completely in products table I wanted to delete product from another table called `likeables` @Ben96

Answer (score 0):

Detach the Products corresponding to the like.

```
public function destroy($product)
{
    Like::where('product_id', $product)
         ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
         ->delete();

    return 'done';
}
```

Comment: If I use this method it deletes  products from database in products table , I wanted to delete a product in another table (likeables) not in products table @linktoahref

Comment: Please share the schema of your `Like` Model.

Comment: I get this `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'like_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: delete from `likeables``  @linktoahref

Answer (score 0):

`findOrFail` will throw an exception which will cause the 404 when it can't find a record. You are using `SoftDeletes` so the record can exist in the database but doesn't mean that it hasn't been 'soft deleted'. If it has been soft deleted the scope will make it act like it isn't there.

Check your record with `id == 4` to see if it has a `deleted_at` column with a value. If it does, it was deleted (soft deleted). You will have to adjust your query to be able to retrieve soft deleted records.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent - Soft Deletes - Querying Soft Deleted Models](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models)